# Are WebApi 2 request calls processed in logical threads of execution from stack?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, clr

When ASP.NET Web Api 2 processes requests in asynchronous manner are they considered logical threads of execution? I.e. does setting up

```
CallContext.LogicalSetData("somekey", "somevalue")
```

before starting the web api stack guarantee getting "somevalue" from

```
CallContext.LogicalGetData("somekey")
```

from anywhere in-code executed during specific request processing?
If it doesn't what is the way to share some variable across several api calls?

Comment: You might want to add a paragraph about what you are trying to achieve, or what scenario this applies to, so people can suggest possible alternate solutions instead of just focusing on this one (which could or could not be the right approach, but right now we can't see if it is).